# @DocumentReference behavior for fields sent to a pub/sub topic

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working with Spring Data MongoDB and I am using @DocumentReference for referencing between documents. And I want to send an object to a pub/sub topic with Google pub/sub.
Example for Account model:

```
@id
ObjectId id;
....
@DocumentReference
Address address;
....
....
```

and Address model:

```
@Id
ObjectId id;
String street;
String city;
```

When I send the Account object in a pub/sub message will it be sent with references as this:
Account:

```
id: 234324abc2312
address: {
    id: 12345123
    street: somthing
    city: somewhere
}
```

or will it be mapped like this?

```
id: 234324abc2312
address: 12345123
...
```

The documentation says it is done in the mapping layer, but I don't know if this is only applicable when saving to the DB.
Appreciate all the help!